# Correct way to run these asynchronous tasks?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, asynchronous, task

I have just started learning how to deal with asynchronous tasks in ASP.NET. I decided to try and implement some asynchronous functionality in one of my methods. I need to get 3 different integers, named ontime, late, and incomp, by accessing the database. This can all be done at the same time as nothing else in the method relies on the output of these calls. After reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh524395.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443(v=vs.110).aspx and this is the code I came up with:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> KPI(int id = 0)
    {
        var ontime = getOnTimeTasks(id);
        var late = getLateTasks(id);
        var incomp = getIncompleteTasks(id);

        await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WhenAll(ontime, late, incomp);
        ViewData["ontime"] = ontime; 
        ViewData["ictasks"] = late;
        ViewData["incomplete"] = incomp;

        return View();
    }

    public async Task<int> getOnTimeTasks(int id)
    {
        return await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => db.Tasks.Include(t => t.Job).Where(t => t.Company == User.Identity.Name && t.RepId == id && t.Complete == true && t.CompleteDate <= t.Job.Deadline).ToList().Count);
    }

    public async Task<int> getLateTasks(int id)
    {
        return await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => db.Tasks.Include(t => t.Job).Where(t => t.Company == User.Identity.Name && t.RepId == id && t.Complete == true && t.CompleteDate > t.Job.Deadline).ToList().Count);
    }

    public async Task<int> getIncompleteTasks(int id)
    {
        return await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => db.Tasks.Include(t => t.Job).Where(t => t.Company == User.Identity.Name && t.RepId == id && t.Complete == false).ToList().Count);
    }
```

I'm not even sure if this will work (run all three tasks simultaneously) so can anyone help a newbie out with this?

**UPDATE: ** I received the following error upon running this code:
`The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you shouldn't use `Task.Run` on ASP.NET. Doing so negates all the benefits of `async`. Instead, use naturally-asynchronous APIs such as EF6's `ToListAsync`.

Secondly, EF6 does allow asynchronous APIs, but *only one call at a time* (per `DbContext`). So, you can either create three different db contexts, or just do them one at a time.

Your final code could look like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> KPI(int id = 0)
{
    ViewData["ontime"] = await getOnTimeTasksAsync(id);
    ViewData["ictasks"] = await getLateTasksAsync(id);
    ViewData["incomplete"] = await getIncompleteTasksAsync(id);
    return View();
}

public Task<int> getOnTimeTasksAsync(int id)
{
    return db.Tasks.Include(t => t.Job).Where(...).CountAsync();
}

public Task<int> getLateTasksAsync(int id)
{
    return db.Tasks.Include(t => t.Job).Where(...).CountAsync();
}

public Task<int> getIncompleteTasksAsync(int id)
{
    return db.Tasks.Include(t => t.Job).Where(...).CountAsync();
}
```

Or, if you want simultaneous calls:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> KPI(int id = 0)
{
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(getOnTimeTasksAsync(id),
        getLateTasksAsync(id), getIncompleteTasksAsync(id));
    ViewData["ontime"] = results[0];
    ViewData["ictasks"] = results[1];
    ViewData["incomplete"] = results[2];
    return View();
}

public Task<int> getOnTimeTasksAsync(int id)
{
    var db = new MyDatabaseContext();
    return db.Tasks.Include(t => t.Job).Where(...).CountAsync();
}

public Task<int> getLateTasksAsync(int id)
{
    var db = new MyDatabaseContext();
    return db.Tasks.Include(t => t.Job).Where(...).CountAsync();
}

public Task<int> getIncompleteTasksAsync(int id)
{
    var db = new MyDatabaseContext();
    return db.Tasks.Include(t => t.Job).Where(...).CountAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Does this still allow me to execute all three "getTasks" functions simultaneously? Even with 'await'?

Comment: @barnacle.m: The current code will run them one at a time. If you want to run them simultaneously, you'll need three different database contexts.

Comment: I can instantiate the context separately for each task, would this allow me to improve performance? None of those tasks rely on one other so they can be executed together.

Comment: If there's just one physical database server, then probably not, because there's just one disk. If it's a database cluster or Azure SQL, then it could possibly improve performance.

Comment: Well ultimately I would want to be executing lots of tasks simultaneously, not just database calls. As a matter of practise, how would I write that code to get those values into the ViewDictionary simultaneously?

Comment: Oooooh. That's what I was looking for. I wonder if this will make any performance difference when there's a few thousand users and tens of thousands of Task objects in the database.